# Updating mongo document failing

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to update a document that is created before a task is performed and then updated a few milliseconds after the task is complete. The problem is that effects of the updates are not being persisted and I'm wondering if its because of the very small time lag (I'm no a DB/mongo expert) or something is wrong in my code. Here is the code for the update:

```
func (r *taskRepoConnection) Update(task *entity.Task) (*entity.Task, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), r.connection.Timeout)
    defer cancel()

    collection := r.connection.Client.Database(r.connection.Database).Collection(userCollectionName)

    filter := bson.D{{"_id", task.ID}}
    update := bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.M{
            "status":                       task.Status,
            "processing_time":              task.ProcessingTime,
        }}}
    opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)

    result, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update, opts)

    // The code below is just meant to see the output
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result ERROR:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result:", result)
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result TYPE:", reflect.TypeOf(result))
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result MatchedCount:", result.MatchedCount)
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result ModifiedCount:", result.ModifiedCount)
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result UpsertedCount:", result.UpsertedCount)
        fmt.Println("UpdateOne() result UpsertedID:", result.UpsertedID)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "repository.Task.Update")
    }

    return task, nil
}
```

The output:

```
UpdateOne() result: &{0 0 1 ObjectID("6169aeabd76ef4eb1f9c5290")}
UpdateOne() result TYPE: *mongo.UpdateResult
UpdateOne() result MatchedCount: 0
UpdateOne() result ModifiedCount: 0
UpdateOne() result UpsertedCount: 1
UpdateOne() result UpsertedID: ObjectID("6169aeabd76ef4eb1f9c5290")
```

Comment: What's the *type* of `task.ID`?

Comment: Its a ObjectId type

Comment: Try setting the `writeConcern` of the update command's options to the number of MongoDB clusters you have or `majority`.

Comment: @Minathe and does the `task.ID` have the correct value? Is there a record in the db with that id? Did the insert before the update successfully complete? Have you tried to add a time.Sleep before the update just to confirm whether or not it is indeed the short time gap between the two operations? On my machine if I do [this](https://play.golang.org/p/JrjiM_h7ZN7) I get the output you see in the comments of that snippet.